# Django: Updating the Integer Field

Tags: python, django

I have an app in which a user can ask a question & answer it. My problem is that I couldn't increase the answer views as the question is called. Have a detailed look,

Here is the model,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    . . .

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_views = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    . . .
```

In my view,

```
def question_detail(request, id):
    my_question = Question.objects.get(id=id)
```

Now in the html file, I can easily print the Question & all of it's related answers by using `my_question.answer_set.all`.

So, as a specific question (`my_question`) is called I wants to increase the number of view on all of it's related answers by 1. How can I do that?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to listen to any [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/), you can directly update all related answers using [`F()`expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

def question_detail(request, id):
    my_question = Question.objects.get(id=id)
    my_question.answer_set.update(answer_views=F('answer_views') + 1)
```

Comment: You forgot the `from django.db.models import F` ;)